# Display Plotly plot inside VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly

I'm trying to use plotly inside of vscode without a jupyter notebook.

When i use

```
import plotly.express as px

fig=px.line(x=[1,2,3,4],y=[1,4,9,16])
fig.show(renderer='vscode')
```

i only see some output in the terminal:

```
{'application/vnd.plotly.v1+json': {'config': {'plotlyServerURL': 'https://plot.ly'}, 'data': [{'hovertemplate': 'x=%{x}<br>y=%{y}<extra></extra>', 'legendgroup': '', 'line': {'color': '#636efa', 'dash': 'solid'}, 'mode': 'lines', 'name': '', 'orientation': 'v', 'showlegend': False, 'type': 'scatter', 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'xaxis': 'x', 'y': [1, 4, 9, 16], 'yaxis': 'y'}], 'layout': {'legend': {'tracegroupgap': 0}, 'margin': {'t': 60}, 'template': {'data': {'bar': [{'error_x': {'color': '#2a3f5f'}, 'error_y': {'color': '#2a3f5f'}, 'marker': {'line': {'color': '#E5ECF6', 'width': 0.5}}, 'type': 'bar'}], 'barpolar': [{'marker': {'line': {'color': '#E5ECF6', 'width': 0.5}}, 'type': 'barpolar'}], 'carpet': [{'aaxis': {'endlinecolor': '#2a3f5f', 'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'minorgridcolor': 'white', 'startlinecolor': '#2a3f5f'}, 'baxis': {'endlinecolor': '#2a3f5f', 'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'minorgridcolor': 'white', 'startlinecolor': '#2a3f5f'}, 'type': 'carpet'}], 'choropleth': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'choropleth'}], 'contour': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']], 'type': 'contour'}], 'contourcarpet': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'contourcarpet'}], 'heatmap': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']], 'type': 'heatmap'}], 'heatmapgl': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']], 'type': 'heatmapgl'}], 'histogram': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'histogram'}], 'histogram2d': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']], 'type': 'histogram2d'}], 'histogram2dcontour': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']], 'type': 'histogram2dcontour'}], 'mesh3d': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'mesh3d'}], 'parcoords': [{'line': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'parcoords'}], 'pie': [{'automargin': True, 'type': 'pie'}], 'scatter': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatter'}], 'scatter3d': [{'line': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatter3d'}], 'scattercarpet': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattercarpet'}], 'scattergeo': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattergeo'}], 'scattergl': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattergl'}], 'scattermapbox': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattermapbox'}], 'scatterpolar': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterpolar'}], 'scatterpolargl': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterpolargl'}], 'scatterternary': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterternary'}], 'surface': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']], 'type': 'surface'}], 'table': [{'cells': {'fill': {'color': '#EBF0F8'}, 'line': {'color': 'white'}}, 'header': {'fill': {'color': '#C8D4E3'}, 'line': {'color': 'white'}}, 'type': 'table'}]}, 'layout': {'annotationdefaults': {'arrowcolor': '#2a3f5f', 'arrowhead': 0, 'arrowwidth': 1}, 'coloraxis': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'colorscale': {'diverging': [[0, '#8e0152'], [0.1, '#c51b7d'], [0.2, '#de77ae'], [0.3, '#f1b6da'], [0.4, '#fde0ef'], [0.5, '#f7f7f7'], [0.6, '#e6f5d0'], [0.7, '#b8e186'], [0.8, '#7fbc41'], [0.9, '#4d9221'], [1, '#276419']], 'sequential': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']], 'sequentialminus': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']]}, 'colorway': ['#636efa', '#EF553B', '#00cc96', '#ab63fa', '#FFA15A', '#19d3f3', '#FF6692', '#B6E880', '#FF97FF', '#FECB52'], 'font': {'color': '#2a3f5f'}, 'geo': {'bgcolor': 'white', 'lakecolor': 'white', 'landcolor': '#E5ECF6', 'showlakes': True, 'showland': True, 'subunitcolor': 'white'}, 'hoverlabel': {'align': 'left'}, 'hovermode': 'closest', 'mapbox': {'style': 'light'}, 'paper_bgcolor': 'white', 'plot_bgcolor': '#E5ECF6', 'polar': {'angularaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}, 'bgcolor': '#E5ECF6', 'radialaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}}, 'scene': {'xaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6', 'gridcolor': 'white', 'gridwidth': 2, 'linecolor': 'white', 'showbackground': True, 'ticks': '', 'zerolinecolor': 'white'}, 'yaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6', 'gridcolor': 'white', 'gridwidth': 2, 'linecolor': 'white', 'showbackground': True, 'ticks': '', 'zerolinecolor': 'white'}, 'zaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6', 'gridcolor': 'white', 'gridwidth': 2, 'linecolor': 'white', 'showbackground': True, 'ticks': '', 'zerolinecolor': 'white'}}, 'shapedefaults': {'line': {'color': '#2a3f5f'}}, 'ternary': {'aaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}, 'baxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}, 'bgcolor': '#E5ECF6', 'caxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}}, 'title': {'x': 0.05}, 'xaxis': {'automargin': True, 'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': '', 'title': {'standoff': 15}, 'zerolinecolor': 'white', 'zerolinewidth': 2}, 'yaxis': {'automargin': True, 'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': '', 'title': {'standoff': 15}, 'zerolinecolor': 'white', 'zerolinewidth': 2}}}, 'xaxis': {'anchor': 'y', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'x'}}, 'yaxis': {'anchor': 'x', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'y'}}}}}
```

When i omit the renderer argument, like

```
import plotly.express as px

fig=px.line(x=[1,2,3,4],y=[1,4,9,16])
fig.show()
```

the plot opens in my default browser, which is not what i want.

Is it either possible to show the figure directly in vscode or can it be opened in a browser tab inside of vscode so i don't have to switch windows?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in the latest Insiders' version of VS Code, when using the Jupyter extension. Could you please retry, and see if the bug has been resolved? Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use the built-in notebook of VS Code, another setting may be necessary to view maps:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers
```

gives this:

### Renderers configuration

```
Default renderer: 'vscode'
Available renderers:
    ['plotly_mimetype', 'jupyterlab', 'nteract', 'vscode',
     'notebook', 'notebook_connected', 'kaggle', 'azure', 'colab',
     'cocalc', 'databricks', 'json', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'svg',
     'pdf', 'browser', 'firefox', 'chrome', 'chromium', 'iframe',
     'iframe_connected', 'sphinx_gallery', 'sphinx_gallery_png']
```

I needed to set:

```
pio.renderers.default = "notebook_connected"
```

to be able to render background maps (e.g. with px.scatter_geo() ).

All the other (non-map) visualizations worked even without this setting, though.

Answer (score 8):

1. For plotting using "`plotly`".

   "`Plotly`" is based on a web application that analyzes a python plotting library. Its drawing effect is displayed on the html page by default, so it is viewed in the browser by default.

   In addition to "Jupyter notebook" can be used to display the drawing in VSCode, we can also view the drawing in the "`Interactive Window`" window:

   [Right-click on the code and select "`Run Current File in Interactive Window`".]

   [image]
2. Use "`matplotlib`" to plot.

   "`Matplotlib`" is a python plotting library. When we use it to plot, the results will be displayed in the python plot window:

   [image]
3. For the built-in browser of VSCode, we usually use it to open the file in the browser through the html file, and the html can be directly rendered and displayed in the browser.

Comment: Please show how to show it in the interactive window

Comment: You can right-click on the code and select "Run Current File in Interactive window".

Comment: @Marvin Noll -How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 8):

One option is to set the default renderer, this works in the cell style mode for Python in VSCode:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "vscode"
```

[Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/)

Comment: this doens't work in my case. 'pio.renderers.default = "notebook"' works.

Answer (score 7):

Just my two cents to this topic.
This minimal working example runs fine in VS code (2022 May)

```py
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px

pio.renderers.default = "notebook"
fig = px.bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[1, 3, 2])
fig.show()
```

[image: example plotly bar plot]

Answer (score 7):

install "Jupyter Notebook Renderers" from vscode extensions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me in 2023

Comment: This solves my problem. need more upvotes!

Answer (score 5):

With the current VS code (2022 Feb) and having your python code run at the interactive window the following render seems to work smoother.

```
pio.renderers.default = "notebook"
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me, perhaps because I am on a MacBook.
I finally resolved the issue by installing the "Jupyter Notebook Renderers" extension from Microsoft https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue with bokeh. Apparently, jupyter makes this difficult. Panel helped me:

```py
import panel as pn

pn.extension()
```

Comment: Here is a better way for bokeh (parallel to plotly):

```python
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

output_notebook(INLINE) 
```